# synchronized,immutable,empty collection

Tags: java, collections, immutability, synchronized

Using Collections class we can make any collection  synchronized,immutable or empty

what are there respective uses, when we need to implement these type of collections

Comment: If this is not homework I don't know what is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After incanting the magick word "google" 3 times, I got this obscure tome which contains the great secrets you are asking for ;-)

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html

Comment: Confess, that you got distracted by PacMan on a first try :).

Comment: @Alex, oh... up to now I thought that was part of the ceremony ;-)

Comment: Ah, comments that are so not going to make sense in the future.